# Nodejs application integrate with Angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Nodejs application created using Express (express genrator) and used handlebars as view engine. Created couple of routes and works fine. Application running on port 3000.

Express routes:

```
...
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/landing', landing);
app.use('/home', home);
app.use('/api', api);
...
```

There is an admin panel separate application built on Angular

Currently Angular application running on port 4200 and uses APIs from NodeJs application which running on port 3000.

Angular application routes

```
const routes : Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/user', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'user',
        component : UserComponent,
        children : [
            { path:'', redirectTo: '/account', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent },
        ]
    },

]
```

NodeJs application folder structure

```
api/
   api.js
bin/
   www
modules/
   mongoose.js
node_modules/
public/
   css/
   fonts/
   img/
   js/
   ngapp/ => Angular resources created with ng build
       inline.bundle.js
       main.bundle.js
       polyfills.bundle.js
       styles.bundle.js
       vendor.bundle.js
routes/
   home.js
   index.js
   landing.js
views/
  common/
       header.hbs
       footer.hbs
  layouts/
       master.hbs
  ngapp/
       index.html => Angular index.html file
  index.hbs
  landing.hbs
  home.hbs
app.js
package.json
```

**What I'm trying:** 
Want to run both NodeJs and Angular application on same port i.e. port 3000.

**What I have done:**
Ran *ng build* and placed index.html file inside */views/ngapp/* of nodejs folder structure.

Created one '*user*' route in nodejs and serving that index.html file of angular application. (May be this is not a good way)

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/ngapp/index.html'));
});
```

Somehow its loaded but encountered an error:
[image]

My question is about how we can integrate Angular Application (may be running on separate route but on the same port) with NodeJs application which already have some routes defined and used view engine to render pages.

Comment: You should provide directory structure to understand this `path.join(__dirname + '/views/ngapp/index.html')` and at least that script with all routes in it

Comment: Found a problem with Angular routes. Instead of `/user` its should be `user` and same for `account`. Now its working.

Comment: Good, sometimes it's enough to look at it once more

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions.

Use your node application to serve the static frontend files. Then you can't really use ng serve (this is probably what you'd do when running live).

You should be able to tell Express to serve static content from an Angular build directory like this:

app.use(express.static('../angular/dist'));
Which would work if you had a file structure like so and were running serve.js with Node:

```
-node server
  -serve.js
-angular 
  -dist/*
```

You can customize as needed by configuring the Angular build folder to be wherever you need it, or use Grunt/Gulp to move files around to the folders you prefer with a build task.

Use nodejs with a different port, and use Angular's proxy config, to have Angular think the api port is actually 4200 (this is probably best during development).

This is primarily a concern during development I reckon, since you most likely wont (and shouldn't) be using ng serve live, so option 2 would be my best recommendation.

To configure a proxy, you create a file in your angular application root directory called proxy.config.json with the following content:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Then when you run ng serve, you run it with ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json instead.